# Retrieve parent document details on querying child documents

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

We have the documents in the index with user and the products

```
[{
    "id": 10,
    "type": "user",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "rating": 4,
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Phone"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Best phone"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "type": "user",
    "name": "Bill Brown",
    "rating": 3,
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 21,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Best phone"
        }
    ]
}]
```

On searching `best phone`, how to retrieve child document + parent documents, ordered by search score?
Result should be something like

```
[{
    "id": 10,
    "type": "user",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "rating": 4,
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Best phone"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "type": "user",
    "name": "Bill Brown",
    "rating": 3,
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 21,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Best phone"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "type": "user",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "rating": 4,
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "product",
            "title": "Phone"
        }
    ]
}]
```

The problem is if we store user details in product document it will be hard to handle cases when user wants to update the name.